# difference between /usr/include and /include

Tags: c, linux, header-files

What is the difference between `/usr/include` and `/include` in a Linux environment?

Regards
venkat

Comment: There is no such directory `/include` in the FHS. Perhaps you meant the subdirectory `include` of a project?

Comment: We have a linux subsite for questions like these that aren't about programming: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There should not be `/include` at the top level (and I'm yet to see it). You should probably take a look at [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).

Answer (score 1):

The path `/usr/include` usually exists, and `/include` doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about the linux file structure is that, though there are recommended standards, it's somewhat up to the user where things should go.  I don't believe there is a /include directory on most standard linux distributions, however it might have been created when you installed something onto the system.

Most languages have a default search directory or directory list for external modules, headers, etc.  In the case of C, /usr/include is the second directory it looks in when using `#include` preprocessor directive with the <> after it.  Using quotes in place of these will cause it to look in the current directory.